# Concealing source of goods when dispersion of goods is public

Tags: society, humans, economy

In a world set in the distant past, People A decides to use People B living a good ways outside the city as their first line of defense and early warning signal.  They have managed to indoctrinate People B by breeding out rebellion and supplying them with all the necessities to facilitate a non-scarcity environment via the river running through the cities, along with the issuance of some habit-forming drugs.  The kicker is that People B do not even know about People A, which is a designed fail-safe.  This is done because People A's population is much smaller than People B's because their procreation procedure has been disrupted, which is why they have the need of "disposable" manpower and to remain covert.

My question is... Could People A keep their existence covert while publicly transporting these goods to People B assuming technology consistent with the medieval period?

Comment: How do people in the distant past conceal the existence of a city from people "living directly outside the city"?

Comment: @sphennings I guess what I meant by directly is that there are no other cities or establishments between them.  The cities are in fact a good distance from each other.

Comment: So, there are two cities, A and B, and the river that flows form A to B brings some goodies. But the people from B never questioned their origin and never traveled upriver?

Comment: You seem to be focusing on the drugs, but the much bigger issue here is that People B have all their basic necessities delivered to them via the river for free, and yet they never bother to see what's upriver?

Comment: I'd like to clarify my VTC.  I don't think it's unclear what you're asking (and I didn't vote that way).  I do believe this isn't a worldbuilding question.  It's a [story-based question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened), and those are off-topic at WB:SE.

Comment: @JBH if I form it as a reality check would it fit world building?

Comment: No.  The problem isn't the tags.  The problem is that this isn't about the world (the environment your people live in).  This kind of question is storybuilding and we only allow such questions when they are very, very strongly tied to the world and its rules.  Remember, this site is dedicated to worldbuilding.  Please take the time to read through the link I provided.

Comment: @JBH I have edited corresponding to the link you sent.  Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: This question is still about a story, and not about a world.

Answer (score 2):

Create a secondary camp.  Put the aviary (or whatever you want to call the birds' roost) in it or near it.  Ship the goods to the secondary camp before sending them to the dependent city.

Now if the people follow the birds back to the source, they find a minor camp.  If that happens, abandon the camp and move the birds.  Or stop using the birds altogether.

I don't know that there would be historical examples of this.  It seems rather complicated.  One group has to support another group purely to serve as a warning if a third group should attack?  And they don't want the warning group to know anything about them?  That seems the long way around.  Historically most groups that were strong enough to do this would not have felt scared enough.

Consider instead supporting mobile trading.  These merchants would travel around and make sure that the periphery has what they need to survive.  The merchants can just tell people that they always travel, carrying goods between communities.  Perhaps they meet other merchants at particular trading posts.

This way, if you lose the merchants, the most they can reveal is the trading posts.  You can abandon the trading posts if necessary.  Or use them as traps for the attackers.  Meanwhile, the merchants bring back intel on how the communities are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I think in a situation such as that, a primitive people would probably just think the birds are gathering the drugs themselves (assuming you aren't packaging them in something People B would recognize as manmade). The seasonal opportunistic hunting instincts of people would probably lend itself to believing this a natural occurrence that should be taken advantage of whenever possible.

There is always risk someone will get intrepid enough to try to find where the birds are getting the product. However, if you kill them fast enough, their disappearance could lend itself to a scenario where it's bad voodoo to be greedy.

Answer (score 0):

Full concealment of the city "A" from city "B" is hardly possible. It might be possible in a highly "mythical" (i.e. fantastic) environment where all travel from city "B" is very difficult, and it is a common knowledge in city "B" that traveling upriver (where city "A" lies) means certain death.

More realistic scenario would be a benefactoring scheme. The cities know of each other and there is bustling trade between them. The location of city "B" is known for abundance of some mineral, like malachite, which is pretty, but not precious at all. City "A" may ensure that they would pay top price for malachite, ensuring that people "B" would keep mining it and stay there. Similarly, they may develop a sudden interest in another mineral, which is happen to be exactly where they want the forces of "B" to gather.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @sphennings First paragraph.